# Bypass the limitations of the FLOAT() function, and calculate more digits

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I've made this procedure (SQL Server) that uses the RAND() function to guess its way to finding definite decimals in the square root of 2, and it's currently only able to identify 14 decimals which is due to the RAND() function using FLOAT which only allows for 15 characters:

```
1.41421356237309 49234300169337075203657
1.41421356237309 51454746218587388284504
```

Is there a way to bypass the limitations of the FLOAT() function, and calculate more digits?

Here is the SP:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[DivideBy2] @IterationCount INT
AS

DECLARE @LowerThan DECIMAL(38,37) = 2
DECLARE @HigherThan DECIMAL(38,37) = 1

DECLARE @Iterations TABLE (Iteration INT, HigherThan DECIMAL(38,37), LowerThan DECIMAL(38,37), CurrentLowValue DECIMAL(38,37), CurrentHighValue DECIMAL(38,37))
DECLARE @CurIteration INT
DECLARE @CurHigherThan DECIMAL(38,37)
DECLARE @CurLowerThan DECIMAL(38,37)
DECLARE @CurWorkingValue1 DECIMAL(38,37)
DECLARE @CurLowValue DECIMAL(38,37)
DECLARE @CurHighValue DECIMAL(38,37)

INSERT INTO @Iterations (Iteration, HigherThan, LowerThan, CurrentLowValue, CurrentHighValue)
VALUES (1, @HigherThan, @LowerThan, 0, 0)

DECLARE @id INT
SET @id = 2
WHILE (@id <= @IterationCount)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Iterations
    VALUES (@id, @HigherThan, 0, 0, 0)

    SELECT @id = @id + 1
END

DECLARE DivideBy2 CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT Iteration, HigherThan, LowerThan, CurrentLowValue, CurrentHighValue FROM @Iterations

OPEN DivideBy2

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN

FETCH NEXT FROM DivideBy2 INTO @CurIteration, @CurHigherThan, @CurLowerThan, @CurLowValue, @CurHighValue

IF @@fetch_status <> 0
BEGIN
  BREAK
END

SET @CurWorkingValue1 = RAND()*(@CurLowerThan-@CurHigherThan)+@CurHigherThan

IF      (@CurWorkingValue1 * @CurWorkingValue1) >= 2
        BEGIN
                UPDATE @Iterations SET LowerThan = @CurWorkingValue1 WHERE Iteration = @CurIteration + 1
                UPDATE @Iterations SET HigherThan = (SELECT HigherThan FROM @Iterations WHERE Iteration = @CurIteration) WHERE Iteration = @CurIteration + 1
                UPDATE @Iterations SET CurrentHighValue = (@CurWorkingValue1 * @CurWorkingValue1) WHERE Iteration = @CurIteration + 1
                UPDATE @Iterations SET CurrentLowValue = (SELECT CurrentLowValue FROM @Iterations WHERE Iteration = @CurIteration) WHERE Iteration = @CurIteration + 1
        END
ELSE
        BEGIN
                UPDATE @Iterations SET HigherThan = @CurWorkingValue1 WHERE Iteration = @CurIteration + 1
                UPDATE @Iterations SET LowerThan = (SELECT LowerThan FROM @Iterations WHERE Iteration = @CurIteration) WHERE Iteration = @CurIteration + 1
                UPDATE @Iterations SET CurrentLowValue = (@CurWorkingValue1 * @CurWorkingValue1) WHERE Iteration = @CurIteration + 1
                UPDATE @Iterations SET CurrentHighValue = (SELECT CurrentHighValue FROM @Iterations WHERE Iteration = @CurIteration) WHERE Iteration = @CurIteration + 1
        END

END
CLOSE DivideBy2
DEALLOCATE DivideBy2

SELECT * FROM @Iterations ORDER BY Iteration DESC
```

**That's cool and all, but why do you want to do that in SQL of all languages?** Well, for the same reason people wanted to get Linux running on iPods that didn't even have color screens back in the early 2000s. Essentially useless, but still really cool you can do that.

Also, tasks like these forces me to use techniques, functions, datatypes etc. that I normally never use at my regular job, so it becomes a way for me to give myself challenges outside the scope of what I know.

With that being said, if anyone have a suggestion for a better language to do this in, I would be very interested in delving into that too. Been itching for something new to bite my teeth in

Comment: Aside... `float` is a data type, not a function.

Comment: In SQL Server the largest capacity float is `float(53)` which is 53 bits of mantissa storage, 15 digits max. Float is also an approximate data type, so shouldn't be used anywhere that accuracy matters. If you need greater precision and scale you may wish to implement a random function in SQLCLR that returns a `decimal` data type.